# Speeding up nested loops in python

Tags: python, performance, loops

How can I speed up this code in python?

```
while ( norm_corr > corr_len ): 

    correlation = 0.0

    for i in xrange(6):
        for j in xrange(6):
            correlation += (p[i] * T_n[j][i]) * ((F[j] - Fbar) * (F[i] - Fbar))      

    Integral += correlation
    T_n =np.mat(T_n) * np.mat(TT)
    T_n = T_n.tolist()
    norm_corr = correlation / variance
```

Here, TT is a fixed 6x6 matrix, p is a fixed 1x6 matrix, and F is fixed 1x6 matrix. T_n is the nth power of TT.

This while loop might be repeated for 10^4 times.

Comment: Is there a reason you want `T_n` to be a list of list instead of a numpy matrix?

Comment: Could you please provide some example data for TT, p, F and T_n. Than this would be a working example to be easily tested (of course, we can create random matrices of our own, but the other way your code would be copy & paste executable (if you also include imports...).

Comment: You may also want to ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you tried running a profiler to see which part of the code is slow? https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: Roughly half of the computational time is consumed by the nested loop and the other half is consumed by the matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do these things quickly is to use Numpy's built-in functions and operators to perform the operations. Numpy is implemented internally with optimized C code and if you set up your computation properly, it will run much faster.

But leveraging Numpy effectively can sometimes be tricky. It's called "vectorizing" your code - you have to figure out how to express it in a way that acts on whole arrays, rather than with explicit loops.

For example in your loop you have `p[i] * T_n[j][i]`, which IMHO can be done with a vector-by-matrix multiplication: if v is 1x6 and m is 6x6 then `v.dot(m)` is 1x6 that computes dot products of `v` with the columns of `m`. You can use transposes and reshapes to work in different dimensions, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried two different methods in order to replace nested loop with a single line of code: list comprehensions, and numpy.einsum. However, nested loops were faster compare to both alternatives.